# IntelliJ changes file type

Tags: intellij-idea

I am having a quirky intellij problem.

I have a folder with a bunch of json files. When I add a specific json with name
`LocalValueCode.json` . InteliJ changes the file type to `.file` .
This only happens with this file specific filename. In file associations settings I have `*.json` as a pattern for my json files.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: I've just tried to replicate this, but it doesn't happen to me. You should add which version you're using. I'm on 2016.3 EAP 163.4396.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to Settings | Editor | File Types and make sure that this name is not associated with any incorrect file type.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a YAML file. I created the file but accidentially made it a text-type file. Then when creating YAML content in that file there was no syntax highlighting. Additionally, a bar was shown on the upper edge of the editor window stating that there are plugins for the file extension *.yml -- of which I had already one installed that worked perfectly with other YAML files.

A grep on the `$HOME/.IdeaIC2018.3` directory with that filename found the `.IdeaIC2018.3/config/options/filetypes.xml` file that contained the following line:

```
<mapping pattern="cassandra-docker.yml" type="PLAIN_TEXT" />
```

After removing that line and restarting IntelliJ the YAML file was correctly recognized as YAML.

Comment: Got a bug with my idea when all files become shell scripts. Adjusting this file helped to fix.
But in more modern idea it will be located under
\Users\{your user}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.3{you version}\options

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and I have an better answer, I'm leaving here for whomever might have the same issue.

If  you go to Preferences > File types  >  Recognized file types (Text) > Registered patterns, you will find the file there registered as an association. Just remove the association and you should be fine.